# How to prevent make from regenerating .gitignore?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm just learning to use `make` and I wanted to use my `Makefile` to generate a simple `.gitignore` file. I've tried to write various versions of the file but none seem to work the way I'd expect. The main problem I have is that the `.gitignore` file is remade every time I run `make` even though nothing has changed.

Here's what I've tried:

```
".gitignore" :
    touch .gitignore
    echo 'node_modules' >> .gitignore
```

This re-appends `node_modules` to the `.gitignore` every time I run `make`. Without the quotes around `.gitignore` it fails with the error: `make: *** No targets.  Stop.`. I tried adding a bogus dependency that doesn't change (i.e. `".gitignore" : Makefile`) but the same rebuilding occurs. I've tried making `.gitignore` depend on itself but it just tells me that the circular dependency was dropped and I get the same behavior. I've tried with GNU make versions 3.81 and 4.3.

I eventually want to generate an entire repository with `make` and I don't want the timestamp on the file to change between runs because that causes problems with `git`.

Comment: Does depend `.gitignore` from any files? So is there a file which change affects the content of `.gitignore`?

Comment: When *do* you want Make to modify that file?

Comment: This doesn't really look like a good use of `make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes are not special characters in a makefile (generally speakig).

A rule like this:

```
".gitignore" :
```

tells make that your target is named, literally, `".gitignore"` (including quotes).  Since there is no file named that way in the directory, make runs your rule to generate it.

Change your rule to remove the quotes:

```
all: .gitignore
.gitignore:
        ...
```

and it should work as you expect.  The reason you can't just use `.gitignore` by itself is that make treats targets that start with a period specially: such a target cannot be the default goal in a makefile.

Comment: Thanks, that works. What is the term for putting a sub-target? like that so I can look into it more?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "sub-target".  One target is determined to be the default goal for that makefile.  Every other target is not a default goal.  You can read more about this here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html